# "ERROR running force:source:push" when doing "cci task run dx_push" to a Developer edition org

Tags: dev-hub, environment-hub, cumulusci

I am doing trailheads

https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/quick-start-lightning-web-components/create-a-hello-world-lightning-web-component?trail_id=build-lightning-web-components

and it gets to a point when I must push some lwc files to an org.

If I create a scratch org it works fine and I can push the files. But I can't connect trailhead to a scratch org (not supported).

So I created a Partner Developer org through environment hub and connected cci with:

```
cci org connect thead-dev001 --login-url https://marktheaddev001-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com
```

But when I try:

```
cci task run dx_push --org thead-dev001
```

I get

```
2021-09-05 12:01:30: Org info updated, writing to keychain
2021-09-05 12:01:30: Beginning task: SFDXOrgTask
2021-09-05 12:01:30: As user: mark@marktheaddev001.claritycx1.com
2021-09-05 12:01:30: In org: 00D5f000001z7mDEAQ
2021-09-05 12:01:30: 
2021-09-05 12:01:30: Running command: sfdx force:source:push
2021-09-05 12:01:38: Return code: 1
stderr: ERROR running force:source:push:  
This command can only be used on orgs that have source tracking enabled, 
such as sandboxes and scratch orgs.
Return code: 1
stderr: ERROR running force:source:push:  
This command can only be used on orgs that have source tracking enabled, 
such as sandboxes and scratch orgs. 

Run this command for more information about debugging errors: cci error --help
```

So I am confused because the documentation says:

https://cumulusci.readthedocs.io/en/stable/connected_orgs.html

> In addition to creating scratch orgs in CumulusCI, you can connect
> persistent orgs to your project to run tasks and flows on them. This
> feature supports use cases such as deploying to a Developer Edition
> org to release a package version, or installing to a sandbox for user
> acceptance testing.

What am I doing wrong?
How can I use cci to deploy lwc files to a developer  org?
Or what can I do to make cci and trailhead play nice together?

I have already selected the option 'Enable Source Tracking in Sandboxes' on the Dev Hub/Environment Hub. But this does not seem to make a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `deploy` task to deploy to a persistent org that does not have source tracking (as Developer Editions do not):

```
 cci task run deploy --org thead-dev001
```

You can use this against Trailhead playgrounds, Developer Editions, sandboxes of all kinds, and production orgs.

Comment: Say @david-reed , any idea what to do if you try that and then get it complaining `src not found` and `deployment package is empty; skipping deployment` ?

Comment: Nevermind, I got it!  Had to add a ` --path force-app\main\default` to the end of your suggested command, based on where the actual "classes," "triggers," etc. folders lived relative to the folder I was running the commands from.